# How to add transition to a hover effect in JavaFX CSS?

Tags: css, javafx, hover, transition, textfield

So, the issue I am having is that I can't find `-fx-transition` or anything of the sort.  Like the title says, I simply want to have a hover effect where a textfield transitions to a darker color over a period of about 0.5s.  I checked the "documentation" [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#slider) or even the much better documentation [here](https://wheelercode.wordpress.com/javafx-css-properties-selectors-list/).  Maybe I'm searching for the wrong type of keyword.  By the way, I would like to avoid using anything but CSS at all costs, as I would like to keep all my styling in one place.  Thanks.

Comment: Creating animations is not supported by JavaFX CSS (unfortunately).

Comment: Also, I fail to see how the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide (link for version 11)](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) is inferior to [your other link](https://wheelercode.wordpress.com/javafx-css-properties-selectors-list/); unless I'm missing something, the latter tells you nothing of the formats used for the values of different properties, _which_ nodes have which properties, or the substructures of the various controls.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  It is what it is.  And the only reason I like the second documentation is for the purpose of finding properties.  It seems like there are pages inside pages, so I can't just do a simple Ctrl-F to find a property I need, then follow up with research on it.  Just my personal preference, of course.